# What is the size of a Weebo background image?

Tags: resolution

Just a quick question do any of you know what the correct resolution size is for a background image on the weebo(chineese twitter) web site ?

here is a link if it helps :)
http://www.weibo.com/3701850141/profile?topnav=1&wvr=6#_loginLayer_1435055184397

Answer (score 0):

It is 800 x 115. A quick Google search told me.

Comment: 800 x 115 doesn't seem right, that seems more of a banner resolution and not a background resolution. :(

Comment: Like Twitter the background size will just depend on your monitors resolution so it will vary from user to user

Comment: right its only because I'm creating a big background image for a page and i was thinking about dimensions in Photoshop that's all.

Anyone know if there is a Photoshop template I can work from ?

Comment: @Jake What kind of template do you need? What is wrong with just making a new document as 800 x 115?

Comment: by 800 x 115 isn't that just the center of the page ? so where all the content goes ? im creating something behind the content and to the right and left.

So ill need the width of the center container where the content is and then the right and left sides of it also.

Comment: http://www.weibo.com/login.php

So basically on that link I provided I would be creating graphics for the blue background right and left sides of the main content.